# Java - how do I check whether a JFrame is closed

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

When a user clicks the red 'X' button of a JFrame, how do I detect whether the JFrame is open or closed? I have a swing timer where the JFrame keeps updating it's label until the user closes down the JFrame.

```
int delay = 1000;           //milliseconds    

final Timer timer = new Timer(delay, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        tempLabel.setVisible(true);
        String tmp = "test";                           
        tempLabel.setText("Temperature :  " + tmp);
        // timer.stop();
    }
});

timer.start();
```

Comment: see WindowStateListener

Comment: @ControlAltDel could you modify my code and show me how to use it  please?

Comment: @fredjohnson, search the forum for examples. You now know the class name to search for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement either the WindowStateListener or the WindowListener. If you use the WindowListener it could look like this:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Foo implements WindowListener {

    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String args[]){
       initTimerComponent();
    }

    private void initTimerComponent() {
      int delay = 1000;           //milliseconds    

      timer = new Timer(delay, null);
      timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            tempLabel.setVisible(true);
            String tmp = "test";                           
            tempLabel.setText("Temperature :  " + tmp);   
          }
      });

      timer.start();  
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
       timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }
}
```

You have to implement them all as WindowListener is an interface and the first concrete class implementing an interface is forced to implement all its abstract methods. But you actually need just one method.

Use this method

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
   timer.stop();
}
```

to stop your timer as soon as the window is closing after the user clicked the red X.

Comment: Consider `WindowAdapter`, which allows overriding individual methods.

Comment: @DiabolicWords but timer.stop is a local variable no? How would it work inside windowClosing()? It doesn't know what timer.stop() is

Comment: I have re-edited my answer above. If you implement the timer like this, it will be visible throughout your entire class.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer*

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        //for closing
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Closing");
        }
        //for closed

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: You just posted some code. Add a description what it does or which part of the question it refers to.

Comment: The answer was good enough to don't need any explanation, at least to a fast copy/paste. Thanks for the snippet.